# Formatting a time field in SSRS after using DateDiff

Tags: reporting-services, time, format, datediff

I have a an expression in SSRS that returns the time difference between 2 date time values (h:m:s). It works, however it is displaying the time with single digits (ie: 1:2:3 instead of 01:02:03. I've tried formatting each section, but SSRS rejects the code. Here is my original code that works producing the single digit time:

```
=IIf(Fields!IncStatusActionType.Value = "TH",
DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) & ":" &
DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) Mod 60 & ":" &
DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) Mod 60, "")
```

I tried using Format just on the hour field to test

`=IIf(Fields!IncStatusActionType.Value = "TH", Format(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), "HH")`, rest of expression....

But it doesn't work. I also tried formatting as "##" and "0#" with no luck.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.ToString("00")` to format the `Long` result of a `DateDiff`:

```
=IIf(Fields!IncStatusActionType.Value = "TH",
CLng(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime))).ToString("00") & ":" &
CLng(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) Mod 60).ToString("00") & ":" &
CLng(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) Mod 60).ToString("00"), "")
```

Comment: tezzo, thanks for the reply I found that I had the formatting command ending in the wrong place. I posted what finally worked. I appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had the formatting command all screwed up. Here is what worked, incase anyone else has a similar issue.

```
=IIf(Fields!IncStatusActionType.Value = "TH",
Format(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)), "00") & ":" &
Format(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) Mod 60, "00") & ":" &
Format(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, CDATE(Fields!ActivityDate.Value), CDATE(Globals!ExecutionTime)) Mod 60, "00"), "")
```